# Does independence only need to hold with with probability 1?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference, independence

When I was taught independence, it says that $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.
But now I am learning BASU's theorem, in which proof, it says that $A$ and $B$ are independent because $P\big\{P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)\big\}=1$.

Why does it true? Does it has any relation with measure theory? I do not know anything about measure theory.

The proof of BASU's theorem can be found at the beginning of [this link](https://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/martin/courses/st522/Principles%20of%20data%20reduction/Basu%27s%20theorem.pdf). And what I ask is on the top of page 3.

In the proof of BASU's theorem, it says that $T$ is a complete statistic and that $\mathbb{E}[P(S=s|T=t)-P(S=s)]=0$. Thus $P\big(P(S=s|T=t)-P(S=s)=0 \big)=1$. Hence $S$ and $T$ are independent.

Comment: Can you link the proof and theorem. I don't think there's much one can do only with this information

Comment: @Adam the proof is at the very beginning of https://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/martin/courses/st522/Principles%20of%20data%20reduction/Basu%27s%20theorem.pdf

Comment: @XingzheHe: Can you point out where in this proof it says what you says it does?  ETA: Ahh, I think I see what you're talking about.  At the top of page 3, yes?  It would be good to spotlight where this is, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes! And I have added part of the proof to the question.

Comment: You need to distinguish between independence of events and independence of random variables. Two *events* $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.  It does not make sense to talk about $P(P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B))$ for events $A$ and $B$.  In your link, $S(X)$ and $T(X)$ are random variables, not events.